# "type object argument after * must be an iterable, not int" When trying to increase x and ycor with turtle

Tags: python

I am using turtle graphics in Python to make a game. I want to use these functions to make the spaceship (represented by a turtle) move left and right:

```
def moveL():
    newpos = f.xcor() - 20
    f.goto(newpos)
def moveR():
    newpos = f.xcor() + 20
    f.goto(newpos)
```

(Here, `f` is the turtle instance, representing a fighter ship.)
But I keep getting that error in the title. I tried putting both xcor's into parenthesis and putting "iter" before them, but that didn't fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ryan, could you please paste the full trace log?

Comment: Shouldn't `goto` need to know the *location* (x & y) of where you want `f` to go?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146. We can only explain error messages that we can actually see, so please copy and paste, starting with the line that say `Traceback (most recent call last):` to the end, formatting it as code. (You can redact user names from file paths if you like.) Please also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and make sure you actually *ask a question*.

Comment: Please also see my edits to the question as you have it so far. The point here is that Stack Overflow is *not a discussion forum*, so questions should be written in a way that focuses on *the problem at hand and the question you have about that problem* - not on your level of skill or experience, your inner thoughts about the process (except insofar as they explain *how you want the code to work*), etc.

Comment: @ScottHunter yeah that worked, probably should've thought of that. Thank you!